# contemporary history or recent history?

Tags: phrase-meaning

For indicating the history  of not far and early past (for example until a century ago) which one describes better? contemporary history or recent history?

Comment: Have you looked up the meaning of **contemporary**? https://www.dictionary.com/browse/contemporary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from sciencedirect.com[1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/social-sciences/contemporary-history#:%7E:text=Contemporary%20history%20refers%20to%20the,or%20even%20post%2D1914%20history.)

"Contemporary history refers to the history of events usually within the lifetime of the historian, although sometimes, in the European or North American context, to post-1945 or even post-1914 history."

That said, if you are having a normal conversation, most people would use "Recent History". "Contemporary History" is for more formal situations, like defending your doctoral dissertation.